# What are the differences between neshama or nefesh yisraelit and neshama or nefesh yehudit in a metaphysical sense?

Tags: sources-mekorot, soul, israel

I recall hearing that there are differences between a neshama or nefesh yisraelit and a neshama or nefesh yehudit in a metaphysical, kabbalistic, drush or sod sense and I would like to know what those differences are? and also more about this topic in general and what the sources are.  I may not be using the precisely correct terminology and I also searched through previous questions and could not find a similar question.

Comment: Hi @ShlomoK welcome to Mi Yodeya! We look forward to seeing you around!

Comment: I think you may be referring to something to do with Tikkun Rachel and Tikkun Leah

Comment: Maybe see *Pischei Shearim, Nesiv Partzuphei Leah ve'Rachel*

Comment: Thanks.  Who is the author of that sefer? I will try to find it.